# Jquery how to bind element when iterating through .each to class method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple js class where i am trying to bind 'click' event on an object to the functions. I am iterating through a list of elements:

```
<ul id="cp">
<li><button id="panel_button_light">Turn Light On</button></li>    
<li>
    <div class="arrow-up" id="panel_button_temp_up"></div>
    <div class="arrow-down" id="panel_button_temp_down"></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

I am not sure what i need to enter in the code below when iterating through the elements so that I can call the class method when clicking them.

This is the js code that i am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var CP = function(widget){
    this.widget_name = widget;
    var self = this;
    this.init = function(){    
        $('#'+this.widget_name).children('li').children('*[id*=panel_]').each(function(self){    
        //I need function here to bind the click event to the class CP
        $("#" + this.id).on('click', $.proxy(this.id, this));
    });
      }
  };
  CP.prototype.panel_button_temp_up= function(){    

  };
  CP.prototype.panel_button_temp_down= function(){    

  };
  CP.prototype.panel_button_light = function(){    

  };
  $( document ).ready(function(){
    var c = new CP("cp");
    c.init();
  });
```

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Gr55Y/) what you want?

Comment: *"I need function here to bind the click event to the class CP"* But which function?

Comment: @FelixKling, I thought the questions was to bind the div with their functions which can be done easily with jQuery.  After reading the question again, I am not sure whats required/asked.

Comment: @FelixKling so when iterating through the elements for example "panel_button_light" i want the "click" event to be tied to "CP.prototype.panel_button_light" function

Comment: I guess i want the button name to match the method name in the class dynamically, however i am not sure if that is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.id` is a string, so `$.proxy(this.id, this)` doesn't make sense. If you want to access the property with the same name on the instance of `cp`, you have to do something like `instance[this.id]`.

For example:

```
var self = this;
this.init = function() {    
    $('#'+this.widget_name).find('[id^=panel_]').each(function() {    
        $(this).on('click', self[this.id]);
    });
};
```

Comment: thank you. that worked perfectly. one thing i changed though was the click to "$("#" + this.id).on('click', $.proxy(self[this.id], self));" since the scope on the "panel_button_light " was set to "button"

Comment: I didn't know which object you wanted `this` to refer to. You can still use `$(this)` though, there is no need to search for the element again if you already have a reference to it.